# Getting the date of the last observation that satisfies a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following pandas data frame.

```
    Firm     Date         Work_day
0   1        2016-11-17   1.0      
1   1        2016-11-18   1.0      
2   1        2016-11-19   0.0      
3   1        2016-11-20   0.0     
4   1        2016-11-21   1.0      
5   1        2016-11-22   1.0      
6   2        2016-12-21   0.0      
7   2        2016-12-22   1.0      
8   2        2016-12-23   0.0      
9   2        2016-12-24   0.0
```

How would I be able to add the following column "Last_working_day", which either is simply the current date (if `Work_day == 1`) or gives the date of the last obs. of the respective firm that has a "Work_day" value of `1.0` (Work_day is a dummy variables for working days here). So the resulting table would look like this.

```
    Firm     Date         Work_day Last_working_day
0   1        2016-11-17   1.0      2016-11-17
1   1        2016-11-18   1.0      2016-11-18
2   1        2016-11-19   0.0      2016-11-18
3   1        2016-11-20   0.0      2016-11-18
4   1        2016-11-21   1.0      2016-11-21
5   1        2016-11-22   1.0      2016-11-22
6   2        2016-12-21   0.0      NaN
7   2        2016-12-22   1.0      2016-12-22
8   2        2016-12-23   0.0      2016-12-22
9   2        2016-12-24   0.0      2016-12-22
```

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `Series.where` to convert all dates to `NaN` where `Work_day = 0`.

Then we use `GroupBy.ffill` to fill the gaps per firm.

```
df['Last_working_day'] = df['Date'].where(df['Work_day'].eq(1))
df['Last_working_day'] = df.groupby('Firm')['Last_working_day'].ffill()

   Firm        Date  Work_day Last_working_day
0     1  2016-11-17       1.0       2016-11-17
1     1  2016-11-18       1.0       2016-11-18
2     1  2016-11-19       0.0       2016-11-18
3     1  2016-11-20       0.0       2016-11-18
4     1  2016-11-21       1.0       2016-11-21
5     1  2016-11-22       1.0       2016-11-22
6     2  2016-12-21       0.0              NaN
7     2  2016-12-22       1.0       2016-12-22
8     2  2016-12-23       0.0       2016-12-22
9     2  2016-12-24       0.0       2016-12-22
```

Note that `Date` has to be sorted ascending (which it is in this case), else sort beforehand:

```
df = df.sort_values('Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace datetimes by mssing values if `0` in `Work_day` with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and last call [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
#if necessary doering per groups
#df = df.sort_values(['Firm','Date'])

df['Last_working_day'] = df['Date'].mask(df['Work_day'].eq(0)).groupby(df['Firm']).ffill()
print (df)
   Firm        Date  Work_day Last_working_day
0     1  2016-11-17       1.0       2016-11-17
1     1  2016-11-18       1.0       2016-11-18
2     1  2016-11-19       0.0       2016-11-18
3     1  2016-11-20       0.0       2016-11-18
4     1  2016-11-21       1.0       2016-11-21
5     1  2016-11-22       1.0       2016-11-22
6     2  2016-12-21       0.0              NaN
7     2  2016-12-22       1.0       2016-12-22
8     2  2016-12-23       0.0       2016-12-22
9     2  2016-12-24       0.0       2016-12-22
```